# Что такое межстрочный интервал?

Tags: документы

"Текст печатается на расстоянии **3** межстрочных интервалов от заголовка".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь имеется в виду:

1. После заголовка необходимо отступить **трехкратным** нажатием на клавишу "Enter" и печатать текст,

или

2. Выделив заголовок, нажать "Абзац->Интервал->**3,0**" и печатать текст?

(Речь о текстовом редакторе Microsoft Word).
Спасибо!

Comment: Ваш вопрос не относится к русскому языку. Возможно, вам помогут, но лучше избегать подобных вопросов в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 1):

У ворда межстрочный интервал - это расстояние между строками в абзаце. Измеряется от нижней линии предыдущей строки до верхней черты следующего (по высоте строчных букв). 
Одинарным называется интервал, равный высоте кегля.

Answer (score 0):

На бумаге будет одно и тоже, но при редактировании имеет  огромное значение. В текстовых документах принято использовать два вида межстрочных интервалов: одинарный и полуторный.
"Текст печатается на расстоянии 3 межстрочных интервалов от заголовка"
Написано ТРЁХ ИНТЕРВАЛОВ, а не ТРОЙНОЙ ИНТЕРВАЛ, значит установите одинарный интервал и трижды нажмите Enter. Сам заголовок в несколько строк печатается с использованием одинарного межстрочного интервала, если не оговорено другое. Если заголовок вы пишите через 1,5 интервала, придется сделать отступ в три полуторных.